# The web page size increases while any movable object go away of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to stop easily without the need of clearing each object gone away?

Please just by client side languages without js libraries (angular.js,..) if possible.

I move the game Environment by:

```
ax = ax + 5;
"background-position-x: "+ ax +"px;"
```

and i move the enemy objects by:

```
gl = gl + 10;
g.setAttribute("style", "left: "+ gl +"px");
```

and the position in css is **absolute**.

Comment: You need to do overflow:hidden on the main container. When objects take negative position, they will be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in style section just insert this for **body** of that page:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        overflow: hidden;
        }
     </style>
```

and Advice you to stop Time interval for the left away objects to decrease memory usage.